# Advantage of declaring variable types

Tags: programming-languages

Someone who's just getting started in programming asked me about the advantage of different approaches programming languages take.

For example, some allow the programmer to omit variable declarations and just use them (like PHP). Others require declaration but not necessarily with a type. And others require a full declaration of the variable (including its type).

So what's the advantage of each approach? Why is it better to (not) declare a variable and/or its type? The ones that don't require a type I believe allow for more efficiency for the programmer. You can just take a variable and use it rather than think about what type it may have at the moment of needing it. And potentially you can change its type later on.

But is there more to it than that?

Comment: I think this question belongs to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are intesrted in knowing is a core distinction between programming languages.  You are describing statically and dynamically typed languages. There are a huge number of resources on this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

THere is a lot more to it then what you described.  Both have their advantages and disadvantages.  Neither is better, but each one might excel at certain tasks.

Comment: A language may or may not require declaring variables, with or without type, _independently_ of static vs. dynamic type system. Of course declarations are rather superfluent in dynamic languages so you typically won't find them there, whereas most static languages are to dumb to do proper type inference, but in a [Hindley-Milner type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner_type_inference) you can in principle get away without declarations completely, and this is still the purest static typing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "Of course declarations are rather superfluent in dynamic languages" You mean type annotations right? Variable declarations without type annotations exist in many dynamically typed programming languages.

Comment: @sepp2k I meant specifically type annotations _in_ declarations.